# Laravel 5 - Updating a user deletes password field in db

Tags: laravel-5

I am running out of ideas. I have a controller method which updates a user record in my database.

There is a form, in which the current user can type in his first and last name, username, email and password. All fields except password are prefilled with the stored values.

When the user leaves the password field empty, the current password will be overwritten. Of course, I tried something with `empty()` and `isset()`.

Here is my controller method:

```
public function update($user_id, Request $request){
    if(Auth::user()->canUpdateUser($user_id)){
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        $inputs = $request->all();

        foreach($inputs as $key => $value){
            if($key === 'password' && !empty($inputs[$key])) {
                $validator = Validator::make($inputs, [
                    'password' => 'confirmed|required'
                ]);
                if ($validator->fails()) {
                    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
                } else {
                    $user->$key = bcrypt($value);
                }
            } elseif($key === 'password_confirmation' || $key === '_token'){
                // Nothing
            } elseif($key === 'username') {
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'username'  => 'unique:users,username,' . $user->id
                ]);
                if($validator->fails()){
                    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
                } else {
                    $user->$key = $value;
                }
            } elseif($key === 'email'){
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'email'  => 'unique:users,email,' . $user->id
                ]);
                if($validator->fails()){
                    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
                } else {
                    $user->$key = $value;
                }
            } else {
                echo $key, "<br>";
                $user->$key = $value;
            }
        }

        $user->save();
        //return back()->with('success', 'Deine Daten wurden geändert');
    } else {
        abort(401);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the for loop through each variable?  Even if you have 2 fields wrong, your way would only return one error at a time.  Just validate and update the user as normal (without the password field), then do a conditional check for the password portion:

```
public function update($user_id, Request $request){
    if(Auth::user()->canUpdateUser($user_id)){
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        $fields = $request->except('password');
            $validator = Validator::make($fields, [
                'email'  => 'unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
                'username'  => 'unique:users,username,' . $user->id
            ]);
            if($validator->fails()){
                return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            } else {
                $user->update($fields);
            }
        }

        $pw = $request->get('password', '');

        if(str_len($pw) && $pw == $request->get('password_confirmation')){
          $user->pw = bcrypt($pw);
        }

        $user->save();

        return back()->with('success', 'Deine Daten wurden geändert');
    } else {
        abort(401);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I wasn't aware of the `$request->except()`-function :)